# onchange don't work on checkbox when there are multiple check

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange

I have many checkbox with onchange event that change line color where is checked :

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="cocheCommande($(this))" name="${NAME_SELECTION}" value="<%=command.getCdeId()%>"  />

function cocheCommande(chk)
{
    alert("test cocheCommande");
    var tr=chk.closest('tr');

    if (chk.is(':checked'))
    {
        tr.css('background','#33EE33');
        tr.nextUntil("tr.entete","tr").css('background','#FFFF33');
    }
    else
    {
        tr.css('background','#D0EED0');
        tr.nextUntil("tr.entete","tr").css('background','#EEEED0');
    }
}
```

I have a function that allows to check everything or uncheck. But if I use, onchange event is never call even though everything is checked.
Why ? And how can I do ?

Comment: you cannot use $(this) in attribute

Comment: you may trigger the event: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can't use $ in the html template; you can, however, pass `this` as the argument to your onchange handler:

HTML:

```
<input onchange="change(this)" type="checkbox" />
```

JS:

```
function change(elem) {
  var element = $(elem);
  console.log(element.next())
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/dx8GoJxHwKa52VFCkn2G?p=preview

Comment: Ok, it works when I check one by one (like before) but when I check everything at the same time with a function, onchange is never call...

Comment: Well, that's another problem :) You should probably change your "select all" function somehow then